# A geometric property of singular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, riemannian-geometry

Let $S\subset M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ be the singular points of the equation $Det=0$. That is $S$ is the critical points of the determinant function.

> What  matrices belongs to $S$, precisely?

Let $M=Det^{-1}\{0\}-S$ be the codimension one submanifold of $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$  which has  a natural Riemannian metric induced by the standard metric of $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})\simeq\mathbb{R}^{n^{2}}.$

> What is  a linear  algebraic  and matrix meaning for  a  matrix $A\in M$ with the  following  property:

**"The sectional curvature of $M$ at $A$ is  independent of  choosing a $2$-plane tangent to $M$ at $A$"**

> What  is  a precise example of this  situation, for $n=2$?

Comment: Q1: The non-invertible matrices.  For Q2, what notion of curvature are you using, which Riemann metric?

Comment: @RyanBudney  for $n=2$ the  only  singular point of  the  determinant is the  zero matrix. By  "singular" I mean critical point.

Comment: @RyanBudney what part of the second question is unclear?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first question has an easy answer. The differential of $\det$ is
$$\sum_{i,j}\hat a_{ij}{\rm d}a_{ij},$$
where $\hat A$ is the cofactor matrix. Thus a singular point is such that $\hat A=0_n$, in other words, it has rank $\le n-2$.

Actually, ${\bf M}_n({\mathbb R})$ can be stratified by the sets $R_0,\ldots,R_n$ of matrices of rank $k=0,\ldots n$ respectively. Each $R_k$ is a submanifold of dimension $k(2n-k)$. $R_k$ is homogeneous, in the sense that ${\bf GL}_n({\mathbb R})\times{\bf GL}_n({\mathbb R})$ operates transitively on it by $(P,Q)\cdot A=PAQ^{-1}$. The relative boundary of $R_k$ is $R_0\cup\cdots\cup R_{k-1}$. In particular, there is no removable singularity.

Comment: and in general in the space of rank r matrices the singular set is the matrices of rank <= r-1

Comment: @DenisSerre thank you for your answer. Among these singularities, are there some removable singularities?