# A line bundle over the manifold of singular matrices

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, matrices, vector-bundles

According to answer of Denis Serre to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/197773/a-geometric-property-of-singular-matrices), the manifold of singular matrices in $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ is defined as follows:
$$M=\{A\in M_{n}(\mathbb{R})\mid \text{rank}(A)=n-1\}$$

So we define a (line bundle) over this manifold:
$$\{(A,v)\in M\times\mathbb{R}^{n}\mid Av=0\}$$.

> Is it  a trivial line bundle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this bundle is not trivial (starting from dimension $2$). Introduce a metric, consider projector to a hyperplane, and rotate this hyperplane through $\pi$ about an axis. You get an orientation reversing loop.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.Before that I post this question, I tried a lot to introduce a nonvanishing global section(for $n=2$). I could not find a global section. But during the computation I realize that I can not prove the local trivialization around $2\times 2$ matrices  with one zero row.  So befor that I learn your answer, could you help me for this local trivialization. On the other hand the restriction of this bundle to matrices without zero rows is trivial. Is not this fact contradictory to your answer?I mean does not your method work for such trestriced bundle?

Comment: I mean that I was not able to define a local non vanishing section around $\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: What is the problem? I'm not good with formulas, but just take the orthogonal projection of the kernel of you variable matrix to the kernel of the fixed one. For a while, it's an isomorphism.

Comment: BTW, I didn't think much about this, but I don't see why the restriction to matrices without zero rows should be trivial: a whole row of zeroes has too high a codimension to affect $w_1$.

Comment: Thanks. Now the local trivialization is OK. So I try to understand your main answer.

Comment: The gobal section for restricted bundle is the following:$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\to (b,-a)+\frac{ac+bd}{\parallel A \parallel_{op}^{2}}(d,-c)$ where the later is the operator norm.

Comment: OK, if $n=2$, having a zero row has codimension $1$, so $w_1$ may change. Concerning my construction, in **this** dimension, you cannot rotate a line without hitting a coordinate line.

Comment: May be an alternative proof( which can be modified for the complex case, too): This line bundle is the pull back of the orthogonal line bundle to the canonical $n-1$-bundle on Grassmanian $G(n-1,n)$ via a natural map from the manifold of singular matrices to $G(n-1,n)$.Yes?

Comment: But how can we prove that  this pull back of that nontrivial line bundle on grassmanian is non trivial?

Comment: I would say that you should speak about the Stiefel manifold $V_{n-1}(\Bbb R^n)$ instead of the Grassmannian, which is an $O(n-1)$- (rather than $\Bbb R^{n-1}$-) bundle over the latter. But I do not quite see why the kernel of a mapshould be orthogonal to its image.

Comment: Could you please more explain on your main answer?: May be  an **precise ** circle which restricted bundle is non trivia? thank you.

Comment: Block-diagonal of identity and the $2$-dimansional $\mathbf x\mapsto\langle\mathbf x,\mathbf a\rangle\mathbf a$, where $\mathbf a(t)=(\cos t,\sin t)$, $t\in[0,\pi]$.

Comment: Is it  a circle while $t\in [0,\pi]$? What is $x$ here. Any way, for $n=2$ the bundle over the following circle (or its transpos) is trivial $\begin{pmatrix} cost&cost\\sint&sint\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @Ali, you are speaking about operators, which are supposed to have arguments. This is $\mathbf{x}$. This **is** a circle in the space of **operators**, albeit not in the space of vectors. If you double this circle by passing to $[0,2\pi]$, you will certainly get a trivial bundle. In your example, the kernel is fixed; hence, it differs from mine. Write down the matrix carefully; apparently, it will contain things like $\sin^2t$ or $\sin t\cos t$, so that it will be $\pi$-periodic.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and comments. Now I understand the answer. Accoring to your answer and comments I understand the mobious bundle can be embedded in our bundle. Your circle is $\gamma (t)=\begin{pmatrix}cos^{2}t&costsint\\costsint&sin^{2}t\end{pmatrix}$.We define $\alpha:[0,\pi]\times\mathbb{R}\to M\times\mathbb{R}^{2}$ with $\alpha(t,v)=(\gamma(t),v(-sint,cost)$. This map pul backs our bundle to the mobious bundle. Thanks again for your interesting idea.

Comment: what about the following two generalization: 1. The manifold of matrix of fixed rank k and the n-k kernel Bundle. 2. The complex case (At least for n=2)?

Comment: All these bundles are (pull-backs of) corresponding tautological ones, which are known to be nontrivial. If memory serves me right, they are all detected by the top class. Say, in the real case, consider $S^k\subset\Bbb R^{k+1}$ (this is enough) and let the operator $H(a)$ be the projection to $a^\perp$, where $a\in S^k$. This defines a map from the **projective space** $S^k/x\sim-x$ to your space, and the pull-back is the (co-)tautological bundle. In the complex case everything is the same, up to dimension of the sphere.

Answer (score 5):

Consider the natural map $M \to\mathbb RP^n$ assigning $x\mapsto ker x$. Then obviously your line bundle arises as the pullback of the tautological bundle. But now you can write down a homotopically non-trivial map $S^1 \to M \to \mathbb RP^n$ (try to restrict your attention to hit $\mathbb RP^1\subset \mathbb RP^n$). No it is a matter of taste to say that the Stiefel Whitney class will be non trivial or considering the non-trivial pullback to $S^1$ etc.

Comment: Actually, you can do even better: $\mathbb{R}P^n$ is a retract of $M$.  Just pick a metric and consider orthogonal projections.

Comment: Note that $M$ consists  of matrices of rank $n-1$, not  of all singular matrices.

Comment: @Dan +1 for your interesting answer. I am sorry that I can not accept two answers.

Comment: @Dan Can one repeat your argument for the complex case?

Comment: you will still get a map to $\mathbb CP^n$. Then the line bundle is trivial if and only if this map is null homotopic.